# How to restore a deleted text in vim

Tags: backup, vim, restore

I'm using Vim to write software, and while coding, accidentally i deleted almost half of my code and saved and exited Vim. is there a way to restore the source code?
I tried `:recover` command but there is no swap file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you deleted the code using one of the `d` commands, the text might still be in one of the numbered registers. Use the `:registers` command to check, and if you see anything that looks promising you can paste it with `"2p` (for example -- you can replace the number with that of whichever register the text is stored in).

Comment: It works and helped me to restore some of the code, but what about the rest ?

Comment: Sorry, but I think you're out of luck for anything else that's missing. Vim only stores the nine most recent deletes/yanks. You might want to [enable persistent undo](https://codeyarns.com/2010/11/27/vim-persistent-undo/) to protect yourself in future, but that won't help you for this particular file.